# sending a JSON String to Server using XML HTTP Request and POST method

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I want to control an embedded system that uses JSON as communication method. On the client i have installed node.js + the xhr module for node.js. Im running the code below in a cmder console emulator but have no luck seeing anything happen on the embedded system side.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://1.100.0.250:9396", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"id":"x","Client_ID":"webinterface","method":"DOutBit","parameter":"[10,1]","jsonrpc":"2.0",protocol:"2H"}));
```

Is there something substaintially  wrong in the code, or does the console emulator cause troubles with external communication? I get no errors on the console.

Comment: You should probably add event listeners for the readystatechange, load, and error events to see what your client code thinks is happening.

Comment: will this also work on console, i mean, will i see an error message?